# Can't find custom font when using attributed title

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xib, uifont

I have custom Chivo font, added via cocoapod.

So, in xib I can find it using `Title Plain`, as you can see:

[image: title Plain]

But if I need to use `Attributed Title` (for example to use 2 types: regular and bold in same string),
I can't find Chivo font: 
[image: selected attributed]
[image: fonts dropdown]

So how to fix this? I sure can use it from code, but wonder if it can work in described way.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you add them in plist ?

Comment: read agian, please :)

Comment: I guess they need to be installed in fonts book in Mac to be shown in that list.